# How to use a state conditionally?

Tags: ansible

I have in a playbook a `blockinfile` which should be present on not depending on the value of a previously set variable. The bruteforce solution is

```
  - name: shorewall rules
    blockinfile:
      dest: /etc/shorewall/rules
      state: present
      block: |
        # settings for machine {{ machine }}
        # outgoing internet
        ACCEPT {{ machine }} int
        # more here
      when: active == "y"

  - name: shorewall rules
    blockinfile:
      dest: /etc/shorewall/rules
      state: absent
      block: |
        # settings for machine {{ machine }}
        # outgoing internet
        ACCEPT {{ machine }} int
        # more here
      when: active == "n"
```

**Is there a way to set a condition in `state`?** Something along the lines of

```
state: present if active == "y" else absent
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
state: "{{ 'present' if active == 'y' else 'absent' }}"
```